problemas con el dark mode con next js y tailwind
"Estoy implementando el modo oscuro en Next.js con Tailwind CSS. He creado un toggle que cambia entre modo claro y oscuro, y también se sincroniza con la preferencia del sistema. El problema es que algunos elementos, como los contenedores, no cambian su estilo cuando uso el toggle, aunque sí responden a la preferencia del sistema. Por ejemplo, tengo un contenedor con la clase className="relative bg-gray-10 dark:bg-gray-900 py-8 md:py-10 px-6 md:pr-16 md:max-w-lg lg:max-w-xl", pero el fondo no cambia al usar el toggle. ¿Cómo puedo asegurarme de que todos los elementos, incluyendo los contenedores, respondan correctamente tanto al toggle como a la preferencia del sistema?
  <div className="relative bg-gray-10 dark:bg-gray-900 py-8 md:py-10 px-6 md:pr-16 md:max-w-lg lg:max-w-xl">

este es el header donde tengo el toggle e implemento el cambio de thema
    "use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Logo from "./logo";
import Dropdown from "@/components/utils/dropdown";
import MobileMenu from "./mobile-menu";
import LogoMorado from "./logo-morado";

export default function Header() {
  const [top, setTop] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Verificar la preferencia del sistema
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    
    // Función para actualizar el tema basado en la preferencia del sistema
    const handleSystemThemeChange = (e: MediaQueryListEvent | MediaQueryList) => {
      const isDarkMode = e.matches;
      setIsChecked(isDarkMode);
      updateTheme(isDarkMode);
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(isDarkMode));
    };

    // Inicializar el estado basado en la preferencia del sistema o el valor almacenado
    const storedDarkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
    if (storedDarkMode === null) {
      handleSystemThemeChange(mediaQuery);
    } else {
      const initialDarkMode = JSON.parse(storedDarkMode);
      setIsChecked(initialDarkMode);
      updateTheme(initialDarkMode);
    }

    // Escuchar cambios en la preferencia del sistema
    mediaQuery.addListener(handleSystemThemeChange);


    const scrollHandler = () => {
      window.pageYOffset > 10 ? setTop(false) : setTop(true);
    };
    scrollHandler();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
      mediaQuery.removeListener(handleSystemThemeChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const updateTheme = (isDark: boolean) => {
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark', isDark);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = isDark ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';
    document.body.style.color = isDark ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';
  };

  const toggleState = () => {
    setIsChecked(prevState => {
      const newState = !prevState;
      updateTheme(newState);
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(newState));
      return newState;
    });
  };


  
  return (
    <header
      className={`fixed w-full z-30 md:bg-opacity-90 transition duration-300 ease-in-out ${
        !top ? "bg-white backdrop-blur-sm shadow-lg" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <div className="max-w-12xl mx-auto px-5 sm:px-4">
        <div className="flex items-center xl:mx-10 justify-between h-16 md:h-20">
          {/* Site branding */}
          <div className="shrink-0 mr-4">
            {!top ? <LogoMorado /> : <Logo />}
          </div>

          {/* Desktop navigation */}
          <nav className="hidden lg-md:flex lg-md:grow">
            {/* Desktop menu links */}
            <ul className="flex grow justify-end flex-wrap items-center">
              <li>
                <Link
                  href="/"
                  className={`px-3 lg:px-5 py-2 flex items-center transition duration-150 ease-in-out ${
                    !top ? "text-black" : "text-white"
                  }`}
                >
                  Inicio
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  href="/about"
                  className={`px-3 lg:px-5 py-2 flex items-center transition duration-150 ease-in-out ${
                    !top ? "text-black" : "text-white"
                  }`}
                >
                  Nosotros
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  href="/tutorials"
                  className={`px-3 lg:px-5 py-2 flex items-center transition duration-150 ease-in-out ${
                    !top ? "text-black" : "text-white"
                  }`}
                >
                  Blog
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  href="/blog"
                  className={`px-3 lg:px-5 py-2 flex items-center transition duration-150 ease-in-out ${
                    !top ? "text-black" : "text-white"
                  }`}
                >
                  Servicios
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  href="/blog"
                  className={`px-3 lg:px-5 py-2 flex items-center transition duration-150 ease-in-out ${
                    !top ? "text-black" : "text-white"
                  }`}
                >
                  Especialidades
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>

            {/* Desktop sign in links */}
            <ul className="flex justify-end flex-wrap items-center">
              <li className="px-5">
                <div className="relative w-[3.25rem] h-7">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="hs-basic-usage"
                    className="sr-only"
                    checked={isChecked}
                    onChange={toggleState}
                  />
                  <label
                    htmlFor="hs-basic-usage"
                    className="absolute inset-0 cursor-pointer bg-morado rounded-full"
                  >
                    <span
                      className="absolute top-0.5 left-0.5 w-6 h-6 rounded-full transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out"
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: isChecked ? "black" : "white",
                        transform: isChecked
                          ? "translateX(calc(3.25rem - 1.5rem - 0.25rem))"
                          : "translateX(0)",
                        boxShadow: "0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                      }}
                    />
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  href="/signup"
                  className="btn-sm text-gray-200 bg-morado hover:bg-hover-morado ml-3"
                >
                  <span>Contactanos</span>
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

          <MobileMenu />
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

